# any program with can show maths steps for simplifying algebra

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, math

I am looking for a program in linux or even a library which can show maths steps for simplifying algebra expressions

Example:

simplify `2(3x+5)`

step1: `2*3x + 2*5`

step2: `6x + 2*5`

solution: `6x + 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Mathomatic does a bit what you want:

```
$ mathomatic <<EOF
> 2(3x+5)
> simplify
> unfactor
> EOF
Mathomatic version 16.0.5
Copyright (C) 1987-2012 George Gesslein II.
200 equation spaces available in RAM; 2 megabytes per equation space.
ANSI color mode enabled; manage by typing "help color".
Anything done here is temporary, unless it is saved or redirected.

#1: 2*((3*x) + 5)


#1: (6*x) + 10


#1: (6*x) + 10


End of input.
ByeBye!! from Mathomatic.
```

Comment: also any python library or Javascript library.

Comment: also want to see the steps of multiplication